# Coding logical code to figuring out who to pay in Poker

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to write a script that will help me calculate how a group of people should pay each other after a poker cash game night.

Currently, I have 2 dictionaries. The 1st dictionary's key will be player name, and the value will be initial buyin. The 2nd dictionary's key will be player name, and the value will be final # of chips on the table.

I will then store the profit and loss of each player in a 3rd dictionary, with key being player's name and value being the profit/loss of that specific player.

Problem I need help with now is to figure out the best way to pay each other, and the best way is defined to be the least # of transactions. Im stuck on the logic and finding a way to code this properly.

For example, say this is the profit/loss dictionary:

```
PLDictionary = {
   'Player1': 200,
   'Player2': 500,
   'Player3': -100,
   'Player4': -500,
   'Player5': -100
}
```

I want the output to be:

```
Player4 pays Player2 500
Player3 pays Player1 100
Player5 pays Player1 100
```

Theoretically, the following output would also work, but its not ideal as more transactions are needed.

```
Player4 pays Player1 200
Player4 pays Player2 300
Player3 pays Player2 100
Player5 pays Player2 100
```

The solution to this problem don't have to revolve around a dictionary. I just used dictionaries because I thought it would be an easy way to keep track of player-chips information.

Comment: what about also providing a more complex example?

Comment: Honestly the solution doesn't have to be perfect. Just trying to write something up so it will save my friends and I some time everytime we play poker. As long as the code can figure out who to pay who, while trying to keep the # of transactions low, thats acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid checking every possible combination you will need some heuristics. I'm not aware of any known algorithm, but one option comes to mind:

- select the largest debit, and the largest credit
- pay the selected credit with the selected debit
- record that payment, and update data (for instance, if the debit was less than the credit, then the debit is eliminated but the credit is only reduced)
- loop until there are no more credits to pay.

Here is a possible implementation:

```
PLDictionary = {
   'Player1': 200,
   'Player2': 500,
   'Player3': -100,
   'Player4': -500,
   'Player5': -100
}
creds = sorted([[credit,player] for player, credit in PLDictionary.items() if credit > 0])
debts = sorted([[abs(debit),player] for player, debit in PLDictionary.items() if debit < 0])
payments=[]
while creds:
    if debts[-1][0] < creds[-1][0]:
        payments.append((debts[-1][1], creds[-1][1], debts[-1][0]))
        creds[-1][0] -= debts[-1][0]
        creds.sort()
        _ = debts.pop()
    elif debts[-1][0] > creds[-1][0]:
        payments.append((debts[-1][1], creds[-1][1], creds[-1][0]))
        debts[-1][0] -= creds[-1][0]
        debts.sort()
        _ = creds.pop()
    else:
        payments.append((debts[-1][1], creds[-1][1], creds[-1][0]))
        _ = debts.pop()
        _ = creds.pop()

for payment in payments:
    print(f'{payment[0]:15} pays {payment[2]:4d} to {payment[1]}')

Player4         pays  500 to Player2
Player5         pays  100 to Player1
Player3         pays  100 to Player1
```

I'm sure this may be optimized a lot, but it should be enough to give you an idea.